# filter and unfilter on ng-click with buttons

Tags: angularjs

hello i have a couple of buttons i want to filter data with, but i can't figure out how to make it unfilter when i click the button again.  I use the normal filtering expression like:

```
<tr ng-repeat='ledata in datas  |  filter:thecondition'></tr>
```

where the thecondition may vary depending on the button clicked, the button's code is the following

```
ng-click="thecondition = {type: 1}"
```

also how can i mark it with ng-class? make the button look pressed? thanks.

Comment: Are you asking what CSS will make the button look depressed, or how to use ng-class to apply CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is that try to implementing your own custom filter.

Something close to:

**custom filter**:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function(items, param1, param2) {
    return items.filter(function(item){ /* your custom conditions */ });
  };
});
```

and in your **html**

```
 <li ng-repeat="item in items | myFilter:'car': 2">
```

Of course you could extend and perform the actions that are more suited to your app needs.

The reason why I recommend the custom filter is because it will allow you a better separation from the view and the business logic; which is more aligned with the MVVM design pattern behind angular.

Answer (score 1):

For toggling the filter, try this:

```
ng-click="thecondition = thecondition ? '' : {type: 1}"
```

The ternary operator will set `thecondition` to an empty string if it has a value, and to the object with type : 1 if it's empty.

To set the class with ng-class, try this:

```
ng-class="{depressed_button: thecondition}"
```

When `thecondition` is truthy, the class depressed_button will be applied.  It's up to you to define the depressed_button class in a stylesheet or elsewhere.

Comment: FYI, I've not tested this solution, but it should put you on the right track.

Comment: You are right this will make it toggle, but not unfilter unless another button is clicked, i was planning on making it unfilter when clicking the same button so set theconition = {filter:null}

Comment: Isn't toggling the filter off the same as "unfiltering"?  I may not understand what you're trying to do.